# How run Postman in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, postman, postman-native-app

Looks like Postman extension is not supported on Chrome anymore.

I tried to run it by clicking on the icon in chrome://extensions/  page.

I searched in net and found this [article](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/api-tools-postman-install.html#)

I removed the Postman extension and downloaded `Postman-linux-x64-7.14.0.tar.gz` file, but I stuck at how to install it to follow the instruction?

- Kubuntu 18, Google Chrome, Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build)
  (64-bit)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sudo apt install snap`
2. `snap install postman`

Try two above commands in the terminal.